# C Ignoring certain lines when reading from stdin

Tags: c, stdin

I have a file I want to read from stdin of the form

```
 char str, int
 char str, int
```

However, there are some "bad" lines in each of these files that I want to ignore completely, which are formatted almost identically, but do not have a leading space at the beginning of the line. IE

```
 char str, int
char str, int //this is a bad line
 char str, int
```

What is the best way in C to read in a file like this? I thought about using `sscanf`, but because of the differing formats between lines, I'm pretty sure it'll just throw a segfault.

Comment: *"I'm pretty sure it'll just throw a segfault"* - no it won't. A segfault is only going to happen if you screw something up. Anyway, seems to me like the easiest way to parse such a file is to read its content line by line through e.g. `getline()` or `fgets()` and then filter out the correctly formatted lines checking if `line[0]` is indeed a space.

Comment: I would _include_ rather then _exclude_; maybe there's some blank lines?